# How to rename a field in rethink while doing a join

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm trying to do a join on 2 tables in rethinkdb with the following query:

```
r.db('testdb')
  .table('eco')
  .eqJoin('project_id', r.db('testdb').table('projects'))
  .map(
    function(){ 
      r.row.merge(function(){ 
        r.expr({'right': r.expr({'p_name': r.row['right']['name']})})
      })
    })
    .without(r.expr({'right': r.expr({'id': True})}))
    .without(r.expr({'right': r.expr({'name': True})}))
    .zip()
I keep getting the following error:
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

There is a name field on the eco table as well as the projects table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use parentheses instead of square bracket to select a field.

```
r.db('testdb')
  .table('eco')
  .eqJoin('project_id', r.db('testdb').table('projects'))
  .map(
    function(doc){ 
      return doc.merge(function(){ 
        return {'right': {'p_name': doc('right')('name')}}
      })
    })
    .without({'right': {'id': True}})
    .without({'right': {'name': True}})
    .zip()
```

Site notes:

- You shouldn't use `r.row` if you use a function -- it's one or the other, not both.
- You don't need to wrap everything in r.expr

Answer (score 1):

I find this notation a bit more concise:

```
r.db('testdb')
  .table('eco')
  .eqJoin('project_id', r.db('testdb').table('projects'))
  .map((doc) => ({
    left: doc('left'),
    right: { p_name: doc('right')('name') }
  }))
  .zip()
```

given you only want `p_name` from `projects` table.